# Remove all deleted files from "changed but not updated" in Git

Tags: git

When I run `git status`, I have a bunch of lines of the form

```
deleted:    dir/file.js
```

I can remove each of these individually with `git checkout -- dir/file.js`, but there must be a less painstaking way to do so. (And yes, I know I should've used `git rm` in the first place...)

[**Update**: As Mark points out below, `git checkout --` actually restores a deleted file, whereas I'd thought that it deleted it from the git index. I was a little baffled, because when you run `git status`, it says:

```
use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory
```

To me, "discard changes" doesn't mean "restore a file you deleted," but in git terminology I suppose this makes sense.]

Comment: I don't understand. `checkout` will restore these deleted files but you say you should have used `git rm` in the first place which would remove the files. Do you want to restore these files to your working tree or remove them from the index as well as your working tree?

Comment: I want to remove them from the index as well, which is what `git checkout -- [filename]` does, whereas `git checkout [filename]` restores the files.

Comment: That's not right, I'm afraid - the `--` in `git checkout -- <filename>` is just a way to make sure that `<filename>` is interpreted as a path rather than the name of a branch (or a tag or a commit).  If `<filename>` isn't the name of a branch (&c.) then both of the forms you mention have the same effect: they restore the file to its state in the index.

Comment: Ah, yikes! Thanks for the correction, Mark.

Comment: "Discard changes" means "undo things I've done in the working directory."  You are discarding changes you've made since the state of the last commit.  Deleting a file is a change, ergo checkout will discard that change by restoring the file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As rampion points out, you can still use `git rm` to stage the deletion of files that have already been deleted in your working copy (e.g. just `git rm dir/file.js` in your case.)  If you have a lot of these files listed as "deleted:" under "Changed but not updated", I would first check that `git ls-files --deleted` produces a list of these files, and, if so, delete them with:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

Answer (score 36):

So, do you want to commit the deletion of those files?
Then use

```
git add -u
git commit
```

Comment: Just to clarify why I preferred the answer that I added, the problem with `git add -u` in this case is that it will also stage any other changes to tracked files in the repository, rather than just the deletions.

Comment: `Rejected Edit from Dialogik:` (Note that this will also stage any other changes to tracked files in the repository, rather than just the deletions - see comments below.)

Answer (score 1):

You can still `git rm` after the fact, but if you want, you can restore all your changed files (including deletions) to the last revision with `git reset --hard`

Comment: I have an issue with `git push` hanging on a large file that was deleted, followed all of above and more. Its not showing in any status logs. But its still hanging on a push. Would your answer fix this if I proceed with a `git rm` after?