# Git still showing deleted files after a commit

Tags: git, git-commit

How can I remove deleted files from my Git repo?

I've deleted a folder of a JavaScript library, which contained many files. I then went to commit the changes like so:

```
git add .
git commit "message"
git status
```

But it shows all those files as "deleted ....".

How can I make them go away?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all deleted files from "changed but not updated" in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169787/remove-all-deleted-files-from-changed-but-not-updated-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776/how-do-i-commit-all-deleted-files-in-git)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If it lists the files under the "to be committed" section, then just proceed with the commit; the files will remain deleted.  (Git tracks deletions too, not just changes.)

If it lists the files under the "changed but not updated" section, then you have two options:

1. Undelete them by restoring the version in the index: `git checkout path/to/folder`
2. Mark them deleted in Git, then commit: `git rm -r path/to/folder`

Comment: I see, and if I have deleted multiple (in all likelihood up to dozens) small files scattered in different folders, do I have to do the git rm for each? Is there a shortcut? Thank You

Comment: Assuming that you have no other changes to stage, or don't mind staging them, `git add -u` will stage all of the deletions at once.

Answer (score 150):

This will add deletes as well.

```
git add -u .
```

Check what's staged to be committed with:

```
git status
```

Comment: git status is showing a file as being deleted when it's still there on the local storage. and running git add doesn't re-add the file, it stages the change to be permanent. how does one modify what change git has automatically detected?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Worked perfect for my issue.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. good job Jamund Ferguson!!

Comment: Worked for me without the dot (`.`).

Answer (score 23):

`git add -u .`

If you type **git status** and the result says *up to date*, but in red it says

*deleted:     folder/example0.jpg 

deleted:     folder/example1.jpg

deleted:     folder/example2.jpg*

You need to enter this for it to be removed permanently `git add -u .`
then all the red text will be marked in green.

**** Dont forget the space between the letter **u** and the **period**

Comment: perfectly described and the right one I am looking for

Answer (score 8):

You need to record that they are indeed meant to be deleted. The same way you record file changes.

Just instead of `git add`, you will use `git rm`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to tell git that it is removed

```
git rm folder
```

or if you do not want to keep them in repo you can add them to .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

I was also having red colored deleted files when I took `pull` from `upstream/master`. I tried different things but nothing worked.
Eventually, I had to revert all changes (committed, staged, unstaged) for my forked branch and had to re-sync my repo with the upstream master branch.

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
git pull upstream master
```

Answer (score 0):

supposing say you want to remove a file and would not want it to be committed:

use the command:

**git reset HEAD filename**

and then do a **git status** to verify if the file to be removed is not appearing

then do a **git commit**

Answer (score 0):

i find myself have an unexpected 'deleted' folder after i 'rm xxx' to delete some local file.

i first create an temp branch and commit the unwant 'deleted' folder and then delete that temp branch.