# Delete files from git index when they are already deleted from fs

Tags: git, filesystems

I have a bunch of files deleted from the fs and listed as deleted in `git status`.

How can I stage this changes faster then running `git rm` for each file?

Comment: You're asking pretty much the same thing as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/git-rm-multiple-files-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk).

Comment: Also essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169787/remove-all-deleted-files-from-changed-but-not-updated-in-git

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

Whenever this question is asked, people suggest `git add -u`, but the problem with that answer is that it also stages other modifications in your working copy, not just deletions.  That might be OK in many situations, but if you want to just stage the deletion of files that have been deleted from the working copy, the suggestion I've made is more precise.

There's actually [a section of the `git rm` documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html#_removing_files_that_have_disappeared_from_the_filesystem) that discusses how to do what you want - I believe that the command suggested in the "Other ways" section is equivalent to what I've suggested here.

Comment: +1. Just out of interest, why the -z/-0? Looks as though `git ls-files --deleted | xargs git rm` will work just as well?

Comment: @Simon Whitaker: that makes the command work even if there are spaces or newlines in the filenames, by saying to output the listed files separated with NUL bytes rather than newlines.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a nice alias: 'rd = "!git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm"' (put that in .gitconfig without the outer single quotes, under [alias]. Then just run 'git rd' next time).

Comment: This does not work on Windows unless you have Cygwin with xargs installed

Comment: On windows w/out Cygwin you can use powershell like so: `git rm $(git ls-files --deleted )`. (Note: this actually works in Bash too assuming a reasonably sized changeset).

Answer (score 15):

Use the `-u`-flag: [man git-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add)

```
git add -u .
```

Comment: Please note: This will add all the files.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402793/6211109

Comment: @Gautam It will add all files to the index, that are already tracked by git. It will _not_ add new files.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git rm --cached "path/to/file"` to stage a single deleted file.

Use `git rm -r --cached -- "path/to/directory"` to stage a complete deleted directory.

Answer (score 2):

`git commit -a` would stage deleted files (as well as modified) and prompt you for your commit message. I usually execute `git commit -av` (verbose) to also see diffs of modified files.

From the [manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html#_description):

> by using the -a switch with the commit
>   command to automatically "add" changes
>   from all known files (i.e. all files
>   that are already listed in the index)
>   and to automatically "rm" files in the
>   index that have been removed from the
>   working tree, and then perform the
>   actual commit;

Answer (score 1):

git add -A

will do the job for you

Comment: The downside is that it adds untracked files too. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

On windows w/out Cygwin *or powershell* you can use like so:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | for /f %f in ('more') do git rm --cached "%f"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the deleted file was in a parent folder that exists then you can simply:

```
git add parent_folder_path/*
```

If that does not work try adding the parent of the parent:

```
git add parent_of_parent_path/parent_folder/*
```

If this is not what you want, see other's answers.