# How to handle a bunch of deleted files under Git?

Tags: git

I have deleted about 20 files from my project. How to commit them with one command instead of `git rm <filename>` them one by one?

Comment: As a comment because it's no proper answer: I often use `git citool`. There, you can interactively pick what to commit (including deletions).

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of at least these three questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6090732/223092 http://stackoverflow.com/q/492558/223092 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3169787/223092

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want to commit all other changes in your working directory at the same time (as `git add -A` would do), you can use

```
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach Will the removed files be visible if I move the head to a previous commit point or are they totally gone?

Comment: @user137717: If the files are committed in an earlier commit, they will still be there.  This command only removes the files that have been deleted from the working directory from the staging area as well.

Answer (score 5):

`git add -A` will add all changes, *including deletions*, to the index. Then commit away.

Comment: I only want to commit my deletions

Comment: `git add -u` would also do, and avoids adding untracked files.